# Passing additional variables to a query

Tags: wp-query

How can we add more arguments to an existing query? Suppose I have in my theme

```
if (!$blog_query) $blog_query = $wp_query;

while( $blog_query->have_posts() ) : $blog_query->the_post();
```

AND I want to add two arguments to the existing query before passing, say:

```
'orderby' => 'post-title',
'order' => 'ASC',
```

How can I add these to the existing $blog_query?

Comment: Where is `$blog_query` coming from in first place?

Comment: At what point do you want to "add two arguments"? The question is unclear and I am not sure it even makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a custom query like $blog_query, add them right in. If you are wanting to change the main query, use the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action to alter the function.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'alter_blog_order' );
function alter_blog_order( $query ) {
    if( $query->is_main_query() and $query->is_post_type_archive( 'post' ) ) {
        $query->set( array( 'orderby' => 'post-title', 'order' => 'ASC' ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the first thing that came to my mind too, but the OP appears to be asking how to add arguments after the object has been created and the posts queried.

Comment: It seems that way, yes. Though I don't understand why you'd ever want to, considering arguments alter the result :P

Answer (score 0):

I think [LINK](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) is self explainable.

Answer (score 0):

My theme sorts posts by date, which is the default behaviour. I want to sort posts alphabetically for some categories, so I was trying to create a loop like 'if is_category( array (1,2,3) { run the full loop with the two arguments written above added to the default query} else {run default loop}'. Here is the full code of my template-blog file '

```
<?php 
if (!$blog_query) $blog_query = $wp_query;
$blogOptions = ($shortcode_values) ? $shortcode_values : $theLayout['blog'];

while( $blog_query->have_posts() ) : $blog_query->the_post();

    // style and layout info
    $postClass = array();

    // images enabled?
    if ($blogOptions['blog_featured_images']) {

        // class
        $postClass[] = ''; //'style-image-left';

        // get thumbnail image
        $thumb = get_post_thumbnail_id(); 

        // image sizes
        $imageW = $blogOptions['image']['width'];
        $imageH = $blogOptions['image']['height'];

        // crop image (default = true)
        $imageCrop = ( $imageW === 0 || $imageH === 0 ) ? false : true; // Setting to FALSE is useful when setting one value so other adjusts automatically

        // get resized image
        // this will return the resized $thumb or placeholder if enabled and no $thumb
        $image = vt_resize( $thumb, '', $imageW, $imageH, $imageCrop );

            // If media field is populated use lightbox for image/video on click
            $popup_link = '';
            if (get_meta('media_url')) {
                $popup_link = '<a href="'. get_meta('media_url') .'" class="popup" title="'. get_meta('media_title') .'">';
            } 
    }

    if (!$image['url']) {
        // no imge
        $postClass[] = 'noImage';
    }

    ?>

    <li class="post-item clearfix">
        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class($postClass); ?>>
            <div class="item-container">

                <?php if ($image['url']) : ?>
                <div class="the-post-image">
                    <?php 
                    if ($popup_link) : 
                        echo $popup_link; 
                    else : ?>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', THEME_NAME ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>">
                    <?php endif; ?>
                        <figure>
                            <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" width="<?php echo $image['width']; ?>" height="<?php echo $image['height']; ?>" />
                        </figure>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <div class="the-post-content">
                    <header class="entry-header">

                        <?php
                        // Author avatar 
                        if ($blogOptions['author_avatar']) :
                            ?>
                            <div class="author-avatar">
                                <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>"><?php echo get_avatar(  get_the_author_meta('ID'), 35, '', get_the_author_meta('display_name')); ?></a>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        endif; ?>

                        <!-- Title / Page Headline -->
                        <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', THEME_NAME ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                        <?php if ($blogOptions['author_name'] || $blogOptions['post_date'] || $blogOptions['comments_link'] || $blogOptions['category_list']) : ?>
                        <div class="post-header-info clearfix" <?php if ( !$blogOptions['author_avatar'] ) : echo 'style="margin-left: 0;"'; endif; ?>>
                            <?php                               
                            // Author name 
                            if ($blogOptions['author_name']) : 
                                ?>
                                <address class="vcard author">
                                    <?php _e( 'by ', THEME_NAME ) . the_author_posts_link(); ?> 
                                </address>
                            <?php 
                            endif;
                            // Comments link
                            if ($blogOptions['comments_link']) : 
                                // comments link ?>
                                <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Comment', THEME_NAME ), __( '1', THEME_NAME ), __( '%', THEME_NAME ), '', '' ); ?></span>
                                <?php 
                            endif;
                            // Category list 
                            if ($blogOptions['category_list']) :
                                if ( count( get_the_category() ) ) :
                                    ?>
                                    <div class="cat-links">
                                        <?php 
                                        // seperator
                                        if ($blogOptions['post_date']) { echo ' <span class="meta-sep">|</span> '; }
                                        //printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Posted in</span> %2$s', THEME_NAME ), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links', get_the_category_list( ', ' ) );
                                        echo get_the_category_list( ', ' ); 
                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php 
                                endif; 
                            endif;
                            // Date Published
                            if ($blogOptions['post_date']) : 
                                ?>
                                <abbr class="published" title="<?php the_time('c'); ?>"><span class="entry-date"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></span></abbr>
                                <?php 
                                //if ($blogOptions['comments_link']) { echo ' <span class="meta-sep">|</span> '; }  // seperator
                            endif;
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    </header>

                    <!-- Content -->
                    <div class="entry-content">
                        <?php
                            // Post content/excerpt
                            if ($blogOptions['use_excerpt']) {
                                if ($blogOptions['excerpt_length'] != '-1')  {
                                    echo customExcerpt(get_the_excerpt(), $blogOptions['excerpt_length']); 
                                }
                            } else {
                                // set $more to 0 or WP will ignore the <!--more--> tags if not on the home page
                                global $more;
                                $more = 0;
                                the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', THEME_NAME ) );
                            }
                            // Read more link
                            if ($blogOptions['read_more'] && $blogOptions['read_more'] != "-1") {
                                $readMore = prep_content($blogOptions['read_more'], 0, 1);
                                echo '<div class="read-more"><a href="'. get_permalink() .'" title="'. $readMore .'" class="read-more-link">'. $readMore .'</a></div>';
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div><!-- END .entry-content -->

                    <!-- Post Footer -->
                    <footer class="post-footer-info">
                        <?php 
                        // tag list
                        if ($blogOptions['tag_list']) :
                            $tags_list = get_the_tag_list( '', ', ' );
                            if ( $tags_list ):  ?>
                            <div class="tag-links">
                                <?php printf( __( '<span class="%1$s">Tagged</span> %2$s', THEME_NAME ), 'entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-tag-links', $tags_list ); ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php 
                            endif; 
                        endif; ?>
                    </footer><!-- END .post-footer-info -->
                </div>

            </div>
        </article>
    </li>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

</ol>
```

)
if ($blogOptions['paging']) get_pagination($blog_query);

?>

'
@rarst @eric-holmes @s-ha-dum @manish